# How do I replace all instances of a string in a column with the value in a dictionary only if the column name matches the key?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataset output from a device. It tells me the concentration of elements in a sample. For each element there is a limit of detection (LOD) and anything measured below that limit (but is not zero) is saved as '<LOD' in the data. I created a dictionary that has the column names of the elements as the keys and the lowest detection limit value (based on the manufacturer) for that element. There are 28 different elements (columns) in the dataset but the number of rows can vary. There are also other columns within the dataset but for simplicity I left those out.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Ti Concentration':{0:2748, 1:3551, 2:1922}, 'V Concentration':{0:'<LOD', 1:'<LOD', 2:345}, 'Cr Concentration': {0:55, 1:100, 2:'<LOD'}})

replace_vals = {'Ti Concentration':25, 'V Concentration':25, 'Cr Concentration':10}
```

.replace will use a dictionary but it looks in the column (key) for the value (value) in the dictionary. I don't want it to search for the value from the dictionary. Instead I want to replace every instance of '<LOD' **with** the value from the matching key in the dictionary.

I tried .map but also can't get it to use the value from the dictionary. I can't figure out the most efficient way even though it seems like it should be simple.

Most recent attempt using .replace:

```
for element in df:                                             
    np.where(df[element].isin(['<LOD']), df.replace(to_replace = '<LOD', value=replace_vals.get(element), inplace=True, regex=True ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass `replace_vals` as `value`:

```
df = df.replace('<LOD', value=replace_vals)
```

Output:

```
   Ti Concentration  V Concentration  Cr Concentration
0              2748               25                55
1              3551               25               100
2              1922              345                10
```

To update the lower values, you can use `clip`:

```
df = df.replace('<LOD', value=replace_vals)\
       .clip(lower=replace_vals, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you! I could have sworn I tried this but there were many iterations. This worked perfectly for what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

[df.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) can take a dict which let you decide which column uses what value A to replace what value B.

> For a DataFrame nested dictionaries, e.g., {'a': {'b': np.nan}}, are
> read as follows: look in column ‘a’ for the value ‘b’ and replace it
> with NaN. The optional value parameter should not be specified to use
> a nested dict in this way. You can nest regular expressions as well.
> Note that column names (the top-level dictionary keys in a nested
> dictionary) cannot be regular expressions.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Ti Concentration':{0:2748, 1:3551, 2:1922}, 
               'V Concentration':{0:'<LOD', 1:'<LOD', 2:345}, 
               'Cr Concentration': {0:55, 1:100, 2:'<LOD'}})

replace_vals = {'Ti Concentration':25, 'V Concentration':25, 'Cr Concentration':10}

replace_vals_for_df = { k : { '<LOD': v } for k,v in replace_vals.items() }

df.replace(replace_vals_for_df)
```

[code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayPTq.png)

Comment: If there is a single value to replace, df.replace(val, replace_vals) is cleaner

Comment: Thank you! I did use the other answer because it worked well but your answer is actually perfect for another part of this same script. I also appreciate the breakdown of the documentation. I reread the part about .replace so many times but could not wrap my brain around getting it to work. Thanks!